# Aggregators in Apache beam with dataflow runner

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to create aggregators to count values that satisfy a condition across all input data . I looked into documentation and found the below for creation .

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/Aggregator ..

I am using : google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all - 2.4.0 (apache beam based)

However I am not able to find the corresponding class in the new beam api.. 
I looked into org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms package .

Can you please let me know how can I use aggregators with dataflow runner in new api . ?

Answer (score 1):

The link you have is for the old SDK (1.x).

In SDK 2.x, you should refer to `apache-beam` SDK. For the `Aggregators` you mentioned, if I understand correctly, it's for adding counters during processing. I guess the corresponding [package](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/package-summary.html) should be `org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics`.

> > Package org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics
> >     Metrics allow exporting information about the execution of a pipeline.

and `org.apache.beam.sdk.metrics.Counter` interface:

> > A metric that reports a single long value and can be incremented or decremented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am currently using counter metrics which suits the current needs. But they don't exactly behave like aggregators. I think Aggregators provide functionality similar to accumulators in spark.  Counter metrics can't be used to accumulate values or data types across nodes.Hence I need to know whether such a feature exists or has been removed for dataflow.
Note: Such a feature exists for spark runner.

Comment: Metrics do accumulate values across nodes. What kind of aggregator are you looking for?

Comment: eg: I need to collect custom user objects satisfying a condition and then at the driver end I will do some transformations on those . AFAIK metrics can increment or decrement  and behave like a counter.  They cannot collect objects satisfying a conditions .  Note: I don't want to use side output for this.

Comment: Any update on this one? I am also facing similar issue when trying to upgrade existing my dataflow pipeline codebase to apache beam sdk one. @Sachin

Comment: @AgungPratama , no I have not found any solution as it was not required at the moment for me . You may check in the newer version whether such feature exists.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there seem to be no replacement for the Aggregator class in Apache Beam SDK 2.X. An alternate solution to count values respecting a condition would be [Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms). By using the GroupBy transform to collect data meeting a condition and then the Combine transform, you can get a count of the input data respecting the condition.